# AFRAME video autoplay

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-safari, augmented-reality, aframe

as a complete programming noob, I have been trying to use MINDAR.JS to put together an AR scene with multiple trackers to play multiple mp4 videos.

It works ok fine on desktop/laptop, but on mobile (iOS 15) the video just won't play in both Safari and Chrome.

I have tried various toggles like autoplay playsinline...etc. but none of them works...

Anyone has a similar experience, is there anything I should add to the code to make an mp4 autoplay on mobile while a tracker is detected?

TIA!

Comment: I recommend sharing simple code with your attempt. Easier to help and suggest solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. Mobile browsers don't allow autoplay and a user has to start the video with a click or a tap. See A-Frame examples https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/video/ https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/test/video/index.html#L8

Comment: thanks Diego,

Yes, we figured out with some backwards investigation. it needs a tap or click to start playing any animation. Now finding a way to add a start screen in front of the camera. 