# A-Frame video not playing, only 1st frame visible

Tags: html, augmented-reality, aframe

I can't seem to get my video playing. At first, it was just a black plane but I managed to get it to the point where I can see the first frame of the video but it doesn't play.I am using MindAR too.

The video is a 4 seconds long 608 x 1408 h.264 MPEG video. I've tried another 1080 x 1920 video but that one just displays a black plane.

Currently only testing on my Macbook Pro 14 Inch, but will eventually be for android and iOS as I'm making a AR publication.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/unreal-realities-test
https://unreal-realities-test.glitch.me

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.1.4/dist/mindar-image.prod.js"></script>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.1.4/dist/mindar-image-aframe.prod.js"></script>
    
    <script>AFRAME.registerComponent("play-on-click", {
  init: function () {
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  },
  play: function () {
    window.addEventListener("click", this.onClick);
  },
  pause: function () {
    window.removeEventListener("click", this.onClick);
  },
  onClick: function (evt) {
    var videoEl = this.el.getAttribute("material").src;
    if (!videoEl) {
      return;
    }
    this.el.object3D.visible = true;
    videoEl.play();
  },
});
</script>
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('hide-on-play', {
  schema: {type: 'selector'},
  init: function () {
    this.onPlaying = this.onPlaying.bind(this);
    this.onPause = this.onPause.bind(this);
    this.el.object3D.visible = !this.data.playing;
  },
  play: function () {
    if (this.data) {
      this.data.addEventListener('playing', this.onPlaying);
      this.data.addEventListener('pause', this.onPause);
    }
  },
  pause: function () {
    if (this.data) {
      this.data.removeEventListener('playing', this.onPlaying);
      this.data.removeEventListener('pause', this.onPause);
    }
  },
  onPlaying: function (evt) {
    this.el.object3D.visible = false;
  },
  onPause: function (evt) {
    this.el.object3D.visible = true;
  }
});</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene
      mindar-image="imageTargetSrc: https://cdn.glitch.global/644ffc8d-f16a-4136-9daf-b2a8d5be4cd1/ASCIItargets.mind?v=1646650005503; maxTrack: 2"
      color-space="sRGB"
      renderer="colorManagement: true, physicallyCorrectLights"
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"
    >
      <a-assets>
        <img
          id="card0"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/644ffc8d-f16a-4136-9daf-b2a8d5be4cd1/Jesper1_2.jpg?v=1645538130237"
        />
        <a-asset-item
          id="card1"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/644ffc8d-f16a-4136-9daf-b2a8d5be4cd1/3D%20Scan%20Test.gltf?v=1645538142025"
        ></a-asset-item>
        <video
          id="video"
          preload="auto"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/644ffc8d-f16a-4136-9daf-b2a8d5be4cd1/NFTDemo.mp4?v=1646662685556"
          autoplay
          loop="true"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          width="1"
          height="0.552"
          webkit-playsinline
        ></video>
      </a-assets>



      <a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 2">
        <a-image
          src="#card0"
          alpha-test="0.5"
          position="0 0 0"
          height="0.552"
          width="1"
          material=""
          geometry=""
        >
        </a-image>
      </a-entity>

      <a-entity mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 1">
        <a-gltf-model
          rotation="0 -270 0"
          position="0 0 0"
          scale="1 1 1"
          src="#card1"
          animation="property: position; to: 0 0.2 0.2; dur: 1000; easing: easeInOutQuad; loop: true; dir: alternate"
        ></a-gltf-model>
      </a-entity>

      <a-entity
        mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0"
        material="shader: flat; src: #video"
        geometry="primitive: plane; width: 2.25; height: 5.25"
        position="0 0 0"
        rotation="0 0 0"
        play-on-click
        visible="false"
      >
      </a-entity>
      
      <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false">
        <a-entity
          position="0 0 -1.5"
          text="align: center;
                width: 4;
                wrapCount: 100;
                color: black;
                value: Tap to allow videos to play"
          hide-on-play="#video">
        
        </a-entity>
      </a-camera>
      
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most browsers today don't allow video autoplay without user consent. You'll need a user click or a tap. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226949/aframe-video-autoplay

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Thanks, I looked at the code from github and made changes but it still does not play. Edited my changes above as well as on Glitch.

Comment: Is [this](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/ar/video_mindar.html) working for You? Unfortunately I don't have a mac, but works on both PC and android.

Answer (score 2):

As per browser policies most browsers today don't allow video autoplay without user consent. You need to capture a click or tap and trigger video playback by calling the `play()` method on the video element. The `click` event cannot be synthesized: A-Frame entities won't work, you need a 2D DOM element that the user clicks (the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) element will work letting the user click anywhere on the screen but can also have some button somewhere that the user needs to tap).

See A-Frame example displaying a modal UI (made with A-Frame) to request the user to start video playback (a component listens for click / taps on the window element): https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/video/

The corresponding component logic can be found at: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/js/play-on-click.js#L16

You need something like the code below:

```
 window.addEventListener('click', function () { 
   document.querySelector('#video').play();
 });
```

I modified your example to illustrate how to play the video on user click. I omitted the mind-ar parts. The video feed covers the UI and I think it's not relevant to the issue: video playback must be triggered by user action.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/roomy-hyper-bear

Notice `play-on-click` and `hide-on-play` are not built-in A-Frame components and you have to import them in your page (see index.html in example above).

Comment: thank you so much, I've managed to get the video playing! The "Click or tap to start video" text only flashes while loading and then disappears when the camera turns on. I used your example but added position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false" to the a-camera because without that the position of everything gets messed up on mobile for some reason.